# Laptop running Ubuntu died, trying to recover data by plugging the drive in as external

Tags: boot, data-recovery

Hello and thank you to the Ubuntu community.
I had a spare laptop and turned it into a plex media server running Ubuntu (latest build, installed in Summer last year). It was a really fun project and worked great, until the laptop of course started to die and sputter. I had opened it up before, so I did so again rather stupidly without backing anything up. Now the laptop won't turn on.

It was a Lenovo Yoga 11s with a 500gb mSATA SSD. I bought a special adapter for mSATA to USB, took out the drive with Ubuntu and all my Plex data on, and plugged it into another computer hoping to boot into it. The first attempt didn't work so I tried another computer, this time a Lenovo ThinkPad T480 running windows. In the Boot Menu, I can choose USB option, but when I hit enter it just refreshes the screen and takes me back to the boot menu as if there is nothing there. Seems my computer won't see the device as bootable for some reason (external boot is enabled UEFI as far as I'm aware as I have booted into other OSs from this machine before).

When I am looking in Windows 10 with the external/internal mSATA-now-USB3 device attached, it shows the drive as a 500GB empty drive.

Any ideas about how to boot back into my beloved Ubuntu machine would be eternally appreciated, or even jut how to look at the drive. I mainly just want to get my Plex data folder back so I can transfer to a proper server (as oppose to an old dying laptop) as a permanent solution.

Many thanks in advance everyone!

Richard

**EDIT**

Have another machine running Linux Mint and when I plug it in there I can see all the files so I can recover my data, but I would still like to BOOT into this drive in order to get my server up and running again until I get the new parts. Many thanks!

Comment: probably you might have to disable secure boot in uefi, to boot from external drive; perhaps even enable "compatibility mode" if the machines it was installled in had a classical bios

Comment: Thanks for that! I will give it a try! Much appreciated.